# ComponentLookupError when trying to create new dexterity objects

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm following [a tutorial](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/reference/manipulating-content-objects) about manipulating dexterity content objects. It explains how to create objects.

```python
from zope.component import createObject
context = createObject('example.type')
```

But I'm not sure what to put instead `example.type`. I tried using `IProduct`, `degu.product.IProduct` and `degu.Product`. But all of them raise a ComponentLookupError.

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.6.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 220, in createObject
    return getUtility(IFactory, __factory_name, context)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniel/.buildout/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.6.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 169, in getUtility
    raise ComponentLookupError(interface, name)
ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass zope.component.interfaces.IFactory>, 'degu.commerce.product.IProduct')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the same name that you used in the the [Dexterity FTI registration](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/schema-driven-types/the-fti).

You can verify what names are registered in the `portal_types` tool:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

typestool = getToolByName(context, 'portal_types')
print typestool.listContentTypes()
```

or visit the `portal_types` tool in the ZMI in your browser and look at the list of types there; they are listed as `typeid (Type Title)` in the tool. If your type isn't listed there ensure that you properly registered your type first.

Note that for this to work, you need the local component manager set up correctly. Normally, this happens automatically, but if you are using a `bin/instance run` script or use `bin/instance debug`, that doesn't happen. You need to do that manually in that case:

```
from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest

app = makerequest(app)
site = app[site_id]
setSite(site)
```

You may also want to set a current user:

```
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager

user = app.acl_users.getUser('admin').__of__(site.acl_users)
newSecurityManager(None, user)
```

Comment: The content type `degu.Product` is listed but I got the same error when trying to use it. Also, context is not defined when using `bin/instance debug` so I used app.Plone instead to get typestool.

Comment: @DanielHernández: Ah, using `bin/instance debug` does not set up the local component manager. That is a *different* problem.

Comment: I have the same problem whit `bin/instance run`.

Comment: @DanielHernández: I explicitly say that in my updated answer that this applies to both `debug` and `run`.